# Error in downloading file from a FTP site

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP()

ftp.cwd('ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_precip/')

*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

Any reason why I am getting the error message above? I can access the FTP site through a browser just ok

Comment: How did you setting user/password for connect to this site?

Comment: no user name or password is needed. see ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_precip

Comment: I tried to connect to this server but fail. So I wondered about the authentication method. However, Let me guest that again.

Comment: Had you tried `ftp.login()` before `ftp.cwd('')`? I think that could help. Because I can't check this solution. So I can't write as an answer.

Comment: Why don't you answer my question but accept the same one? Mr.@user308827

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code tries to create an unconnected FTP instance and then change in this unconnected instance to a directory called `ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_precip/`. There are several things wrong with it: first you need to connect to the server, then you need to login (anonymous login in this case) and then you can change to the real directory instead of some URL used as directory name:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.cdc.noaa.gov')
ftp.login('ftp','user@example.com')
ftp.cwd('/Datasets/cpc_global_precip/')
print(ftp.retrlines('LIST'))
```